# Python word counting program for .txt files keeps on showing string index out of range as an error code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im pretty new to this and i was trying to write a program which counts the words in txt files. There is probably a better way of doing this, but this was the idea i came up with, so i wanted to go through with it. I just don´t understand, why i, or any variable, does´nt work for as an index for the string of the page, that i´m counting on...
Do you guys have a solution or should i just take a different approach?

```
page = open("venv\harrry_potter.txt", "r")
alphabet = "qwertzuiopüasdfghjklöäyxcvbnmßQWERTZUIOPÜASDFGHJKLÖÄYXCVBNM"

# Counting the characters

list_of_lines = page.readlines()
characternum = 0
textstr = ""    # to convert the .txt file to string

for line in list_of_lines:
    for character in line:
        characternum += 1
        textstr += character

# Counting the words

i = 0
wordnum = 1

while i <= characternum: 
    if textstr[i] not in alphabet and textstr[i+1] in alphabet:
        wordnum += 1
    i += 1


print(wordnum)

page.close()
```

Counting the characters and converting the .txt file to string is done a bit weird, because i thought the other way could be the source of the problem...
Can you help me please?

Comment: Valid range for `i` is `0` to `len(characternum) - 1`. You are going past that.

Comment: `list_of_lines = page.readlines()` just use `page.read()` it will return you a string already of the whole text (not the most efficient way of doing this anyways but at least you won't need to have a loop to get a string of text)

Comment: You actually have two questions in one here.  You are getting Answers to the second one "Is there a better way".  The answers to the first one "What's wrong with my code" is in the comments.   But for future questions, please include the *actual* error you are getting and the line in question (which should be in the error message), so the many folks here who wish to help can get a picture without having to figure out your code or run it themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the tipps! I'll try them out tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Typically you want to use split for simplistically counting words. They way you are doing it you will get right-minded as two words, or don't as 2 words. If you can just rely on spaces then you can just use split like this:

```
book = "Hello, my name is Inigo Montoya, you killed my father, prepare to die."
words = book.split()
print(f'word count = {len(words)}')
```

you can also use parameters to split to add more options if the given doesn't suit you.

https://pythonexamples.org/python-count-number-of-words-in-text-file/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the Split commqnd untill now. That make it way easyer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the word count of a text file
The shortest code is this (that I could come up with):

```py
with open('lorem.txt', 'r') as file:
    print(len(file.read().split()))
```

First of for smaller files this is fine but this loads all of the data into the memory so not that great for large files. First of use a context manager (`with`), it helps with error handling an other stuff. What happens is you print the length of the whole file read and split by space so `file.read()` reads the whole file and returns a string, so you use `.split()` on it and it splits the whole string by space and returns a list of each word in between spaces so you get the lenght of that.

A better approach would be this:

```py
word_count = 0
with open('lorem.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        word_count += len(line.split())
print(word_count)
```

Because here the whole file is not saved into memory, you read each line separately and overwrite the previous in the memory. Here again for each line you split it by space and measure the length of the returned list, then add to the total word count. At the end simply print out the total word count.

Useful sources:

- [about `with`](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python)
- [Context Managers - Efficiently Managing Resources (to learn how they work a bit in detail) by Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aKFBoZpiqA)
- [`.split()` "docs"](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the Split command untill now. That helps a lot. I'll also use with.